# How to prioritize and throttle requests in Java?

Tags: java, throttling

My application handles Web Service requests(real time requests and a batch program firing requests) and calls an external system to retreive data.
External system has a limit on requests, it can handle x calls in y seconds.

Not only I need to throttle but need to prioritize the requests as well. I need to make sure Real time requests have precedence over batch requests.

Our application is running on clustered Jboss server. What is the best way to prioritize and throttle the requests?

Comment: Similar to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329599/can-i-throttle-requests-made-by-a-distributed-app

Comment: I did go through that post earlier. I wasn't sure if few of the solutions suggested met my requirements, as most of them were for throttling and not prioritizing. I appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have an application that pretty much has the same requirements. I have a processor thread that holds a reference to several `BlockingQueue`s.

The thread class itself looks like the following:

```
public class Processor extends Thread{
   BlockingQueue<Msg> highPriorityQueue = new BlockingQueue<Msg>();
   BlockingQueue<Msg> mediumPriorityQueue = new BlockingQueue<Msg>();
   BlockingQueue<Msg> lowPriorityQueue = new BlockingQueue<Msg>();

   public void ProcessMessage(Msg msg, int priority){
      // Add msg to one of the queues according to priority
   }
   public void run(){
      while(!interrupted()){
          // process messages by priorities
          if(highPriorityQueue.size()>0){
          }
          if(mediumPriorityQueue .size()>0){
          }
          if(lowPriorityQueue .size()>0){
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks GETah!!. Is this manageable in Clustered environment? I meant all requests from my n servers on clustered environment should not exceed the x calls.

Comment: If your servers are all independent then there should not be a problem. Otherwise, you need some kind of communication to synchronize their states

Comment: They are not. Anyway thanks for your post and I will check how to synchronize their states across the servers.

Comment: Another way to do it @Rams is to have one server in your cluster handle all of the requests to your service.  It might be easier to just ship the requests to the one server as opposed to synchronizing state across all servers.

Comment: Doesn't it mean i am not using other servers in the cluster to process? and I might have to change the load balancer settings right?. Pardon my ignorance!!

Comment: @Rams Glad you found my post useful +1 if you think it was of some help for you :)

Answer (score 0):

For handling the throttling in a clustered environment, look into implementing a Token bucket algorithm.

At it's core, X number of tokens are placed into a bucket every Y time interval. Every time you need to do something that is throttled, you remove a token from the bucket. If the bucket is empty, you block until you get a token. Adjust X and Y to provide reasonable throttling. This can be done with a custom server. I've even seen some implementations that take advantage of Memcached.

As for prioritized queuing, you may want to look at a PriorityQueue or BlockingPriorityQueue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DelayQueue to throttle the requests. Here is an example on throttling:

https://gist.github.com/1713624

Answer (score 0):

You can use an open source system for that: http://code.google.com/p/valogato/